# How do I find out more about the error "first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'..."

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

The C# line below generates an error:

```
Excel.Worksheet wks = (Excel.Worksheet)wbk.Worksheets.Add(After: wbk.Worksheets.Count);
```

I intend for the code to create a new worksheet in the workbook `wbk`, but no new worksheet is created. Instead I get an error.

The error message I receive is:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll

How do I learn more about this error so that I can resolve it?

View detail tells me nothing that makes sense to me. Check the error code property of the exception to determine the HRESULT returned by the COM object tells me nothing that makes sense to me.

I don't know how to move forward with error searching from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What property or method call exactly fires the exception?

I'd recommend breaking the chain of calls and declaring each property or method on a separate line of code. Thus, you will be able to find the exact one which fires the exception.

Also try to specify optional parameters explicitly:

```
Excel.Worksheet wks = (Excel.Worksheet)wbk.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, wbk.Worksheets[1], Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Pay attention to the fact that you need to specify the sheet after which the new sheet is added, not a number!

Answer (score 0):

The error message:
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll

Is just a notification from a handled exception, you should have a try catch surround your call:
Excel.Worksheet wks = (Excel.Worksheet)wbk.Worksheets.Add(After: wbk.Worksheets.Count);

Try intercept the real exception.